# SharedPreferences Fragment not work

Tags: android

I try call SharedPreferences, and I pass a parameters but not work (not update and not put data)

I don't know I do wrong?

```
public void put(String value){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("isFirstRunCheck", value);

    editor.commit();
}

public void checkFirstRun3(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    String name ="";
    if (restoredText != null) {
        name = prefs.getString("isFirstRunCheck", "");//"No name defined" is the default value.
    }
    if(name.equals("true")){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click si ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click no ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I put my "put()" I do not see it work

```
 if(cbx.isChecked()){
            put("true");
        }else{
            put("false");
        }

          cbx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(cbx.isChecked()){
                    put("true");
                }else{
                    put("false");
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: So just to clarify, name is getting set equal to "No name defined"?

Comment: I don't see you ever calling `put()`.

Comment: ("isFirstRunCheck", "this is a default value"); , I only pass "si" or "no", but always get nothing

Comment: @Tanis.7x editor.putString("isFirstRunCheck", value);

Comment: Where you calling put() method ?

Comment: @Warped I mean *his* `put()` method, not `SharedPreferences`'s.

Comment: I update my post  @Tanis.7x

Comment: Solved, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551830/save-spinner-with-sharedpreferences-in-fragment-onitemselectedlistener"  line master : getActivity().getBaseContext()

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
```

Use

```
spe.putString("yourStringKey", yourStringValue).commit()
```

and then get your data using the "yourStringKey"

and don't forget to call your `put(someData)` method.

Comment: I need specify where is my data ("pref".. How I can link?

Comment: Updated the answer, but I think your main problem is that you don't use your put() method (or at least did not post code where you use it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't think this is working, but I'm guessing it is because your code doesn't do what you think it does.

First of all, the comment on this line is wrong:

```
name = prefs.getString("isFirstRunCheck", "");//"No name defined" is the default value.
```

The second parameter to `getString()` is the default value- in this case you are specify that the default value should be an empty string if you have not previously saved a value to the "isFirstRunCheck" key.

Second, you seem to be expecting a value of "si". However, you are only ever calling `put("true")` and `put("false")`- you never call `put("si")`, so your conditional in `checkFirstRun3()` will always be false.

As an aside, a String is an odd way to save boolean data. `SharedPreferences` has a `getBoolean()` and a `putBoolean()` that will likely suit your needs better.

Comment: Sorry the value is update now I pass false/true  I update my post.

Comment: Any idea that ocurred ?

Comment: Well, I'm questioning whether the code you posted is actually the code you are running, so it is difficult to make any further suggestions.

Comment: I tried this code and not work always get default value ("") == null